# How to reuse deftype methods in Clojure / Clojurescript?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I'm trying to extend library [DomKM/silk](https://github.com/DomKM/silk).

Specifically there's `deftype Route` which implements protocol `Pattern`, which has method implementations, which I'd like to reuse in my custom implementation of `Pattern` protocol.

https://github.com/DomKM/silk/blob/master/src/domkm/silk.cljx#L355

```
(deftype Route [name pattern]
  Pattern
  (-match [this -url]
          (when-let [params (match pattern (url -url))]
            (assoc params ::name name ::pattern pattern)))
  (-unmatch [this params]
            (->> (dissoc params ::name ::pattern)
                 (unmatch pattern)
                 url))
  (-match-validator [_]
                    map?)
  (-unmatch-validators [_]
                       {}))
```

Ok so my implementation would look somehow like this, but I'd like to "inherit" `Route`'s methods. I mean execute some custom logic first and then pass it to original `Route` methods.

```
(deftype MyRoute [name pattern]
  silk/Pattern
  (-match [this -url] 
    true) ;match logic here
  (-unmatch [this {nm ::name :as params}]
    true) ;unmatch logic here
  (-match-validator [_] map?)
  (-unmatch-validators [_] {}))
```

How is this done in clojure / clojurescript?

Comment: Clojure's designers are not fond of inheritance of methods.  I don't think you can do this in a very natural way.  You can obviously create a `Route` object and let `MyRoute`'s methods delegate to the `Route`'s.  Objects created by `deftype` are Java classes, so you might be able do what you want by using one of the two Java interop macros that allow inheritance: `proxy` and `gen-class`.  `gen-class` is probably overkill, so if you take this path, I suggest `proxy`.  However, this goes against the design goals of Clojure, so you might want to simply reimplement the code you need.

Comment: The functions in `Route` are not large.  If you want to do this a lot, you could write functions outside of the `deftype` objects and call them using `Pattern` methods.

Comment: @Mars Thanks for an answer! When I tried to use proxy: `(proxy [Route] [name pattern] (-match []))` I get an error `java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class`. Is it even possible to use proxy on deftype?

Comment: Maybe not.  I wasn't sure.  It doesn't surprise me that it doesn't work, I guess.   Although it doesn't say you can't extend  deftypes, the "Datatypes and protocols are opinionated" section of Clojure's [datatypes](http://clojure.org/datatypes) page will give you the idea.  Clojure is intended to encourage certain kinds of programming, while retaining a lot of flexibility.  Sometimes there's less flexibility than one wanted in a particular situation, but languages are full of tradeoffs.

Comment: I ended up using [juxt/bidi](https://github.com/juxt/bidi). It's better designed for extensibility. I already achieved elegant solution for my problem with it. Thanks again

Comment: I didn't look close enough into this but I believe that potemkin can do this with `def-abstract-type`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to redef the type. Referring to "ancestor" protocol implementation is possible, from another namespace.

```
user=> (ns ns1)
nil
ns1=> (defprotocol P (f [o]))
P
ns1=> (deftype T [] P (f [_] 1))
ns1.T
ns1=> (f (T.))
1
ns1=> (ns ns2)
nil
ns2=> (defprotocol P (f [o]))
P
ns2=> (extend-protocol P ns1.T (f [o] (+ 1 (ns1/f o))))
nil
ns2=> (f (ns1.T.))
2
```

Keep in mind that `ns1.P` and `ns2.P` are totally different cats, both called `P`.